Emoji displaying in black and white in a Text Component, but normally in a TextInput Component
I am encountering an issue in one of my tasks where the "Face with Tears of Joy" emoji () displays in black and white instead of in color when used within a Text component, whereas in a TextInput component, it displays normally. I have added a screenshot below for more clarification.

Can anyone explain why this discrepancy occurs and how I might resolve it so that the emoji displays in color in both components?
if (isDescriptionText) {
  return (
    <>
      <TextInput
        multiline
        placeholderTextColor={theme.secondary}
        placeholder="Write something..."
        value={description}
        onChangeText={handleChange}
        onContentSizeChange={(event) => {
          setInputHeight(event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height + 57);
        }}
        style={styles.input}
        onFocus={handleFocus}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
        {...testProps}
      />

      
      <Text>{description}</Text>
    </>
  );

In a textInput Component emoji is displaying normally, but in a Text Component it turns black. I want it to display normally in Text components as well.

Questions get closed when enough users vote to close; there is no single user who decides to close your post. I have voted to reopen this now; for the future, please review the [help] and in particular How to ask as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].
